# Node: How to restructure nested JSON data getting and organize reusable?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Using a Node request module, I am getting JSON data through an URL. The JSON file is nested in multiple levels and not organized in a way you can reuse. Current JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "series": {
      "brochure_image": "range.jpg",
      "background_image": "range.jpg",
      "Model 1": {
        "medium_images": "Model_1.png",
        "brand": "Tesla",
        "Model 101": {
          "medium_images": "Model_101.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_101.png",
        },
        "Model 102": {
          "medium_images": "Model_102.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_102.png",
        }
      },
      "Model 2": {
        "medium_images": "Model_2.png",
        "brand": "Tesla",
        "Model 201": {
          "medium_images": "Model_201.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_201.png",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to restructure so I can easily access the data from the front end. I want to change like this:

```
[
  {
    "series":"Model 1",
    "model": [
      {
        "modelName": "Model 101",
        "medium_images": "Model_101.png",
        "brochure_image": "Model_101.png"
      },
      {
        "modelName": "Model 102",
        "medium_images": "Model_102.png",
        "brochure_image": "Model_102.png"
      }
    ] 
  }
  {
    "series":"Model 2",
    "model": [
      {
        "modelName": "Model 201",
        "medium_images": "Model_101.png",
        "brochure_image": "Model_101.png"
      }
    ] 
  }
]
```

How can I do this? My node server.js getting part looks like this:

```
const dataUrl = "http://example.com/data/series-data.json";

// API
app.get("/api/getSeriesData", (req, res) => {
    request.get(dataUrl, (error, response, body) => {
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        var seriesObj = json.data.series;
        var seriesArr = [];

        for (var series in seriesObj) {

            if (seriesObj.hasOwnProperty(series)) {
                seriesArr.push({"series": series, "model": seriesObj[series]});
            }
        }
        res.send(seriesArr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

We can remove the unwanted `keys` in the object then loop through the object properties and add them to the array.

Please go through the snippet and let me know if you face any issues or doubts.

```js
var data = {
  "data": {
    "series": {
      "brochure_image": "range.jpg",
      "background_image": "range.jpg",
      "Model 1": {
        "medium_images": "Model_1.png",
        "brand": "Tesla",
        "Model 101": {
          "medium_images": "Model_101.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_101.png",
        },
        "Model 102": {
          "medium_images": "Model_102.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_102.png",
        }
      },
      "Model 2": {
        "medium_images": "Model_2.png",
        "brand": "Tesla",
        "Model 201": {
          "medium_images": "Model_201.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_201.png",
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
var output = [];
delete data.data.series.brochure_image
delete data.data.series.background_image
for (k in data.data.series) {
  var temp = [];
  delete data.data.series[k].medium_images;
  delete data.data.series[k].brand;
  for (j in data.data.series[k]) {
    temp.push({
      modelName: j,
      medium_images: data.data.series[k][j].medium_images,
      brochure_image: data.data.series[k][j].brochure_image
    });
  }
  output.push({
    "series": k,
    model: temp
  });
}
console.log(output);
```

```css
 .as-console {
 height: 100%;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me solve my issue. I read somewhere that 'delete' method is slower. I'll look for any alternative way for that.

Comment: @billgajen Yes, that will be best, just refer the snippet and use the same method to achieve the desired JSON Structure, You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
var obj = {
  "data": {
    "series": {
      "brochure_image": "range.jpg",
      "background_image": "range.jpg",
      "Model 1": {
        "medium_images": "Model_1.png",
        "brand": "Tesla",
        "Model 101": {
          "medium_images": "Model_101.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_101.png",
        },
        "Model 102": {
          "medium_images": "Model_102.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_102.png",
        }
      },
      "Model 2": {
        "medium_images": "Model_2.png",
        "brand": "Tesla",
        "Model 201": {
          "medium_images": "Model_201.png",
          "brochure_image": "Model_201.png",
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

var result = [];
Object.keys(obj.data.series).forEach(key => {
  if(key.indexOf("Model") === 0){
      var o = {series: key, model:[]};
      Object.keys(obj.data.series[key]).forEach(k => {
        if(k.indexOf("Model") === 0){
            o.model.push({modelName: k, medium_image: obj.data.series[key][k].medium_image, brochure_image: obj.data.series[key][k].brochure_image});
        }
      });
    result.push(o);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

What this does is to loop through all the properties of the `.data.series` and `data.series[MODEL NAME]` and only consider those values of which property name starts with **Model**. If not all the values that you're interested in have their property name start with **Model**, this approach won't work. In those cases, you'll probably have to use a negative assertion (check if their property name isn't one of the known ones you're not interested in).

Comment: Thank you @Titus. Unfortunately, not all the property name starts with Model.